# Keeping part of a string that overlaps based on a condition BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two tables that look like this

table_1

| store_no | store_loc | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | CAL | ID123 |
| 6789 | LAL | ID947 |
| 5678 | PAA | ID456 |
| 5678 | PAA | ID654 |
| 9876 | LAS | ID789 |

table_2

| ID | client_no | client_name | product |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID123 | 1029 | John Doe | tent blue |
| ID947 | 1029 | John Doe | tent red |
| ID456 | 4538 | Jane Doe | skates 42 |
| ID654 | 4538 | Jane Doe | skates black red |
| ID789 | 9234 | John Smith | bag green |

I am trying to remove the parts of the 'product' that don't overlap if the 'store_no' and 'store_loc' match. So given these two tables I'm looking to get the following as a result:

| ID | client_no | client_name | product |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID123 | 1029 | John Doe | tent blue |
| ID947 | 1029 | John Doe | tent red |
| ID456 | 4538 | Jane Doe | skates |
| ID789 | 9234 | John Smith | bag green |

As in the example, I don't have a defined strings that I need removed, the string could be a number or a word. That's why I need a way to extract only the part that overlaps.

I think I need to use IF and REGEXP, but I'm not sure how to do it. I don't know how to make sure I'm only keeping the part of the string that overlaps given a condition.

Comment: Are you sure that you cannot operate with a normalized data instead?

Comment: I could combine the tables, but I still wouldn’t know how to keep the overlapping parts of the string to remove duplicates.

Comment: I meant keeping each product in its own row.

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below simple approach

```
select t.*
from table_1
join table_2 t using (ID) 
qualify row_number() over(partition by store_no, store_loc order by ID) = 1
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

```
Row ID    client_no client_name product
1   ID123 1029      John Doe    tent blue
2   ID456 4538      Jane Doe    skates 42
3   ID947 1029      John Doe    tent red
4   ID789 9234      John Smith  bag green
```